# I want to update the owner of the Lead based on Zip code

Tags: trigger

I want to update the Lead Owner based on Zip Code. I have created a Zip Code custom and imported the zipcodes in to custom object and assigned user for the Zip codes. Now i required to change the owner of the Lead record while creating the record form Force.com sites page. Can anyone help me over her.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
raju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done through 2 ways.

1. site page
2. trigger

I have done through trigger.

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert) {
    Map<String,Id> zipCodeUserMap = new Map<String,Id>();
    for(customObject__c custom : [Select id,zipCode, user from customObject__c]) {
        zipCodeUserMap.put(custom.zipCode,custom.user);    
    }
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new) {
        if(zipCodeUserMap.containsKey(l.zipCode)) {
            l.Ownerid = zipCodeUserMap.get(l.zipcode)
        }

    }
}
```

same logic can be implemented in vf page if you need

Comment: I'm getting an error while creating an record form my site page. Error is as below  Record ID: cannot specify Id in an insert call

Comment: how can we use for the event after insert...? Actualy i'm sending an email to User if the record is matched with zipcode.